# Why was my question closed or down voted?

Tags: discussion, faq, close-reasons, down-votes

Help! My question was closed (or down voted).  Why? And what can I do about it?

- [Downvoted](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6484#6484)
- [Duplicate](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6485#6485)
- Off topic

  - [What technology to take up next](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6486/)
  - [Recommend a software library, tool, book, research paper, blog, forum, or other resource](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487)
  - [Career or education advice](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6488/)
  - [Legal Advice or Aid](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8335/)
  - [Assistance in writing or debugging existing code](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7742/)

    - (MSE) [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in/129632#129632)
  - [Are you still confused about what Programmers (now called Software Engineering) is for?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5654/are-you-still-confused-about-what-programmers-is-for)
- [Unclear](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6489#6489)
- [Too broad](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490)
- [Primarily opinion-based](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491)
- [Other](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6492#6492)
  certification, homework, interview, current events, cross-posting etc...

Three of categories listed under *Off topic* match site-specific close reasons, see: [What should our predefined off-topic reasons be?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5992/what-should-our-predefined-off-topic-reasons-be)

The answers below try to summarize the issue and provide links to related content that helped shape the policies.  Realize that many of the links are from particular points in the history of Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers.SE) and while they have good advice and ideas in them, policies described in 2010 may not be the same as 2014 and beyond.

<sub>Please note: There are quite a few of my answers in this question.  Up voting (or down voting) them all in one go *may* lead to a [serial vote](//meta.stackexchange.com/tags/serial-voting/info) reversal.  If this happens, it makes it even harder for you to vote on other things I may have written elsewhere on this meta.  In that light, please limit your voting on this question and its answers.</sub>

<sub>For pasting into chat or comments there is a "Quick link" at the end of each answer.  The quick link for the question is `[Why was my question closed or down voted?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6483/)` - pasting this into chat or a comment will link to the question.</sub>

Comment: had questions closed for ops not capable of reading and understanding them - or failed bounties for ops not able to reproduce the results. the only effect it has is, that one may realize, that time can be used more meaningful.

Comment: Thanks for this post - very informative :)

Comment: @ChrisCirefice thank you.  Each StackExchange has its own nuances of understanding the various close reasons and P.SE is no exception there.  These interpretations are often found scattered through meta and it can be difficult for someone to grasp all that history from just the close reason summary, and thus the attempt to pull it all together. If someone reads this early on in their P.SE asking career, they may find it possible to avoid many of the common problems and close reasons that we face and thus ask better questions from the start.

Comment: @MichaelT Exactly - my first question here was closed & deleted - I went to chat to figure out why and it was fine. This post didn't exist back then :P I think every SE site should have a stickied (FAQ'd) page like this to help out new users. I don't think a lot of them do, unfortunately =/

Comment: Compared to other SE sites, Programmers is special. It is one of the older sites, and it has gone through iterations regarding its content. Most of the sites in this network started with highly focused goals, and have not changed course in the middle like Programmers has. That seems to make Programmers more difficult to grok for most new members.

Comment: @Snowman I wouldn't say *middle*, but it had a very disruptive bit in the early part of its history (within weeks of going to public beta).  However, a fair bit of the "this is what programmers is" for people who don't participate was set down during that period.  The idea that we still are that "Not Programming Related" site lingers on in quite a few minds (regularly sending questions for "this doesn't fit on Stack Overflow, try on Prorammers.SE"). Some seem to think that P.SE is the worldbuilding.SE version of SO where one can throw anything at the wall to see if it sticks.

Comment: @MichaelT perhaps "middle" was the wrong word. Regardless, the fact is that many old questions linger on this site that are poor examples of questions under the new contents of the help center. Someone can search first (good!), find a poor quality question that was not closed and did receive positive attention (votes, answers), ask a similar question, then wonder why it is downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 17):

## Off Topic

#### Career or education advice

> Questions seeking career or education advice are off topic here. They are only meaningful to the asker and do not generate lasting value for the broader programming community. Furthermore, in most cases, any answer is going to be a subjective opinion that may not take into account all the nuances of a (your) particular circumstance.

Career advice questions are only applicable to the person asking the question.  No two people are looking at the same set of classes, or the same job.  Every question that is asked is either only for one person or the answers will always be hopelessly incomplete because of the lack of the nuanced information and context that the person asking the question is in.

Career questions are often **very important** questions to the person asking them.  Although assistance can be provided, the answer is one that *you* need to find yourself, and not from random strangers on the Internet.  If you are in academia, ask a career counselor at the school, or one of the instructors - they know you better than we do.  Similar resources can be found for people in the job market already.

One of the biggest difficulties with Q&A for career questions is that to get the nuances of your situation and getting to know you better requires a dense two way communication - lots of clarification back and forth.  To this end, [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard) is a resource where (the current) denizens can have that conversation.  We still won't get to know you as well as people who know you know you, but on the whole we are familiar with the various parts of the software industry.

Please also note that we are notoriously bad at predicting the future.  If you had asked someone if Objective C was going to be a popular language (prior to the iPhone) they would have looked at you funny ("[Apple has less than a 2% market share](http://www.macworld.com/article/1043741/marketshare.html) - who would use it?") - yet it became a *very* popular language and subsequently fell out of favor once Apple switched to Swift.  Or if you asked about running JavaScript outside of the web browser they would have laughed at you.  Technology is changing at an incredible rate and to ask about what it will be in another decade? Your guess is as good as mine... maybe better (its less hampered by a few decades of industry preconceptions).

Asking questions to predict the future job market and what skills are best is completely speculation and cannot have any right answer.

#### Related reading

- (Reddit) [/r/cscareersquestions FAQ](http://www.reddit.com/r/cscareerquestions/wiki/index)
- [Are Career Advice questions useful to anyone except the poster?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/are-career-advice-questions-useful-to-anyone-except-the-poster)
- [Are career questions acceptable or not?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5746/are-career-questions-acceptable-or-not)
- [Are now all questions about teaching programming to be considered off topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6594/are-now-all-questions-about-teaching-programming-to-be-considered-off-topic)
- (MSE) [Where to ask for general advice for young programmers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216589/where-to-ask-for-general-advice-for-young-programmers)
- Workplace.SE -> [topics guidance](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
  Workplace.SE -> [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Quick link: <sub><sup>`[Why was my question closed as "Off Topic - Career or Educational Advice?"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6488/)`</sup></sub>

Comment: This one will forever be a problem because programmers are people. Ultimately a more adequate name for this SE site would have been Programming.

Comment: @AndrewHoffman There is a [long](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3718/change-the-name-of-programmers-to-something-that-more-accurately-reflects-the-si) and [contentious](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3718?lq=1) history of the name (and scope) of the site.  The best approach now is likely to help people clearly understand the scope if they have had their question closed or want more information after reading the [help center](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: And the #1 thing that would help people clearly understand the scope would be to 1) Rename 2) Make the scope prominent and one-click away. Imagine if the UX SE site's scope was actually restricted to UI. Oops..

Comment: Why does this answer talk about which technology to learn when http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6486/2114 also does so?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm People frequently are asking about which technology to pick up in the context of career advice. While there is an overlap between this close reason and the other, this close reason is often used for the "what to study" and "what will be more marketable" while the other is often used for the more nebulous "I want to write some code - what should I write it in?" type questions.

Answer (score 9):

## Too Broad

The question you have asked either:

- has too many possible answers
- would require answers that are too long.

#### Polling / Big List of Things

Some questions are just polls for a design, or pattern, or name of a thing. If the accepted answer is based on "which answer I like best," rather than "which answer solves my problem," the question is probably a poll.

While some other Stack Exchanges allow it, Software Engineering SE frowns upon ['big list' type questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/list-questions/info) that seem to want to compile a list of things.  Questions that fall into this category typically have the form of:

- What are all the problems I will encounter with XYZ?
- What are the pros and cons of XYZ?
- How can XYZ be used?
- Any ideas?

Questions like these don't pose a problem that can be solved by an answer.  There is no definitive *right* answer that someone can go to, see the accepted answer and say "yep, that is the answer."

#### Too long

> Can someone explain Java to me?

This question is too broad.  There is far too much in Java to explain it to a person.  While long and complete answers are a good thing, questions that would require books to answer completely don't make good questions.

Often these questions can be resolved by spending some time thinking about what the core problem is or what the first problem you are running into is.

#### Related reading

- [Where to start?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6366/)
- [How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6629/)
- [Green fields, blue skies, and the white board - what is too broad?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6961/)
- [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7537/)
- (MSE) [Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75674/the-halting-problem-or-the-fallacy-of-real-questions-have-answers/75717#75717)
- (MSE) [Is a question that specifically asks for a summary of a broad topic valuable to Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234642/is-a-question-that-specifically-asks-for-a-summary-of-a-broad-topic-valuable-to)
- [Help Center > What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

  > Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.
  >
  > If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about `______`”, then you should not be asking here.

Quick link: <sub><sup>`[Why was my question closed as "Too Broad?"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6490/)`</sup></sub>

Answer (score 8):

## Off Topic

#### What technology to take up next

> Questions about **what language, technology, or project one should take up next** are off topic on Software Engineering.SE, as they can only attract subjective opinions for answers. There are too many individual factors behind the question to create answers that will have lasting value. You may be able to get help in [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard), our chat room.

There is a constant stream of new projects out there.  Github [claims 4,500 new projects a day](https://github.com/blog/841-those-are-some-big-numbers) back in 2011.  On December 23, 2013, Github had [10 million repositories](https://github.com/blog/1724-10-million-repositories).  Quite frankly, there are far too many projects for anyone to suggest a good answer.  What's more, the projects of yesteryear may well be inactive now.

The same problem exists for suggesting languages and technologies - they are constantly changing.  Further, many questions of this type often just ask "which one is best" without specifying any requirements, making them essentially a popularity poll.  If you really *do* want a popularity poll, consider reading [The Top Programming Languages: IEEE Spectrum’s 2014 Ranking](http://spectrum.ieee.org/static/interactive-the-top-programming-languages) which takes into account such things as Github active projects, Stack Overflow questions, Reddit questions, Hacker News, and job postings (see the 'custom' ranking for working with weightings).

A goal for Stack Exchange is to create a lasting repository of information.  Asking questions about which technology to chose runs counter to that.  In part because everyone's needs are different and also that everyone has their own favorites.

#### Related reading

- [How does one keep up with all the new tools/languages/framework?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56848/how-does-one-keep-up-with-all-the-new-tools-languages-framework) (also look at the [linked questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/56848?lq=1))
- (SO Blog) [Gorilla vs. Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)
- (SO Blog) [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)
- If you really want some projects:

  - [/r/dailyprogrammer](http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer)
  - [Mega Project List](https://github.com/karan/Projects)

Quick link: <sub><sup>`[Why was my question closed as "Off Topic - What Technology to Take Up Next?"](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/6486/)`</sup></sub>

Comment: Is it worth merging this into the resource request answer now that the close reasons are merged? While I am sure there are existing comments that would break, they are likely on questions that are mostly already closed and deleted.

Answer (score 7):

## Unclear what you are asking

What you are looking for, in the [context of Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is unclear.

This close reason can also be a bit unclear as to what the issue is.  Please be sure to:

- Give enough context that someone reading the question can understand it
- Explain what you are looking for
- Check to make sure you are not using jargon that is particular to one specific branch of computing (and if you are, either change the jargon or link to a site that explains it)
- Check that there are no hidden assumption or "leaps of thought" in your question. They might be obvious to you, but they won't be to the wider community. It is often better to spell it all out explicitly, even if you think it is blindingly obvious.
- Make sure you are on the proper site

The last point is important too.  This close reason is often used as a proxy for "we don't think that this question is a good question for Software Engineering SE (it might be on Stack Overflow), but would get closed there too."

Explain your design.  Explain what you have done.  Explain where you are having difficulty.  Explain what you are looking for.

#### Related reading

- [How to ask](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)
- [Unclear what help you need](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6404/31260) (see also [linked MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215806/165773))
- [Why is research important?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important)
- [How to ask "how to understand some code" questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7513/how-to-ask-how-to-understand-some-code-questions)

Quick link: <sub><sup>`[Why was my question closed as "Unclear?"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6489/)`</sup></sub>

Answer (score 7):

## Primarily opinion-based

Good questions ask for expertise, not opinions. Examples of questions that are primarily opinion-based:

- "What did this person mean when he said..." (We're not mind-readers)
- "Which of these two designs is the better one?" (what do you mean by "better?")
- "How should I arrange the folders in my project?" (really?)
- "Is this the best practice?" (what do you mean by "best?")
- "What is the name of this thing so I can go look it up?" (Ask us your specific question about the thing)

The key distinguishing factor is that there is no way to get an authoritative answer for the question - the answers are all based on opinion rather than the knowledge of the person answering the question.

Consider that if the answers to the question of:

> I like ${design A} for these reasons

> I like ${design B} for these other reasons

If both of these answers are valid then the question is likely opinion based.

#### Related reading

- [The real borderline for "Opinion based" in Programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6473/the-real-borderline-for-opinion-based-in-programmers)
- [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6742/on-discussions-and-why-they-dont-make-good-questions)
- [Discuss this ${blog}](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6417/discuss-this-blog)
- [On the troubles of naming and terminology](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology)
- [What is the problem with "Pros and Cons"?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/what-is-the-problem-with-pros-and-cons)
- (MSE) [The halting problem - or - the fallacy of “real questions have answers”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75674/the-halting-problem-or-the-fallacy-of-real-questions-have-answers/75717#75717)
- (MSE) [How can I encourage Stack Overflow to rein in the 'subjective' vigilantes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167516/how-can-i-encourage-stack-overflow-to-rein-in-the-subjective-vigilantes/200144#200144)

  > **tl;dr** We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out...
- (MSE) [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/142354#142354)

Quick link: <sub><sup>`[Why was my question closed as "Primarily Opinion-Based?"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6491/)`</sup></sub>

Comment: "the answers are all based on opinion” - that doesn't seem a good criteria (not least because it's a opinionated claim). I appreciate we're looking to find objective rather than subjective answers. Yet even so called authorative answers are in fact subjective, and thus opinions, on a well-informed basis alright. If that were not so, only one answer per question would ever be given, by the most authorative person on the site. A better reason and criteria would be 'has caused back-and-forth arguments without reaching a conclusion, as demonstrated by comments and answers'.

Comment: so bitter, opinions matter, I usually want to know the opinion of people who knows more than me, and stack exchange sites are a good place to do so. What if knowledgeable people just write for the joy of share what they are, and not to answer a question or earn reputation. The community will suffer? I don't think so, it's just the system needs to be better classifying information, and let user know when is reading a "too opinionated/discussed question", but no need to close, storage is cheap, and noise means system is not filtering.

Comment: @juanpastas ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: @juanpastas opinions do matter, but the site is poorly designed for having an opinion poll or discussion. Its specifically designed for questions that have specific answers or solutions. The site can't do everything ideally for all types of questions and so we try to focus on just those it can do Really Well. There is a bit more about this in [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6742/40980).

Comment: @juanpastas You said: "noise means system is not filtering."  And that's exactly what the community is doing - filtering out the noise so the signal remains high.  If you're looking for opinions, StackExchange is not the right community for that goal.  While there are opinions, StackExchange is built around high quality questions and answers.

Comment: @juanpastas: "stack exchange sites are a good place to do so" – No, they are absolutely *terrible* for that. There is no way to have a discussion about opinions on SE. You are looking for a discussion platform, not a Question/Answer platform. There are many of those, SE is not one of them.

Comment: @MichaelT thanks for your link very illustrative, now I understand more, not all people takes the time to explain it  in a concise way as you did.

Answer (score 6):

## Downvoted

The first thing to look at is the mouseover for the down vote button.

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

Realize that this is a completely subjective grading and people may down vote because they were late to work or don't like unicorns.  However one's feeling of unicorns, this *is* information for you to look at and consider how to improve the question.

#### Make sure that the question is not just asking for something that can be easily searched with google.

Asking other people to do your searching for you is considered poor form.  Everyone answering questions is doing so on a volunteer basis (even the SE employees that sometimes answer questions - they aren't paid to do so).

This also extends to things that you should have been able to find when searching on Software Engineering SE.  As you enter the information be sure to tag the question appropriately.  The combination of tags and title *may* help you find something right away that answers the question.

#### Explain your current understanding of the issue

Just saying "Could someone explain ${concept} to me" doesn't show what you *do* understand.  It lacks research.  Often the answer to this is spent repeating what is already available in Wikipedia.  If you had read this already and don't understand a part of it, explain that part and what you do understand.  Correcting a misconception is easier (and a better question) than trying to explain the entire topic.

#### Blatantly off topic

Make sure you read the help center on [on-topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [off-topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) questions. Questions that are asking for a discussion, or polling or one of the reasons specified in the help center are often down voted.  Especially note that questions *should* have been posted on Stack Overflow (implementation) or questions that should have been posted on Stack Overflow, but would be off topic there too (do this work for me) are similarly often down voted.

#### Related reading

- [Why is research important?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important)
- (MSE) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380)
- (MSE) [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2373/165773)

Quick link:

`[Why was my question down voted?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6484/)`

Comment: When you have an answer downvoted that is years old, and no comment is left, it is hard to care about unicorns.  I have taken to just deleting my answer even if it has been accepted as 'the' answer.

Answer (score 6):

## Duplicate questions

A duplicate question in and of itself [isn't a bad thing](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).  Often it means that the people who have suggested it as such think that the answer to your question is already in the original question.  Questions are closed as duplicates because we want future readers to be able to go to one place to find the answer.

Make sure you read *all* of the answers on the original question and consider the implications behind the answers too - not just the first reading.  An example of this can be seen on Stack Overflow when debugging questions trying to track down a `NullPointerException` in Java are linked to a question that explains about `NullPointerExceptions` rather than trying to resolve that particular instance.

If you feel that something is closed as a duplicate incorrectly, edit your question to explain specifically how it differs from the other question and the answers in the duplicate question do not apply to your situation.

#### Related reading

- (MSE FAQ) [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)
- (MSE) [Changes to “close as duplicate” (part deux)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux)
- (MSE) [Does the new guidance on duplicate questions suggest closing a question as duplicate, if the original answers the OP's question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217401/does-the-new-guidance-on-duplicate-questions-suggest-closing-a-question-as-dupli)
- (MSE) [Someone flagged my question as already answered, but it's not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not)

Quick link: <sub><sup>`[Why was my question closed as a duplicate?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/6485/)`</sup></sub>

Answer (score 6):

## Off Topic

#### Recommend tools, libraries, programming languages, resources (including books, blogs, tutorials, and examples), or projects to undertake

> Questions asking us to **find or recommend tools, libraries, programming languages, resources (including books, blogs, tutorials, and examples), or projects to undertake** are off-topic here as they attract opinionated answers that won't have lasting value to others. You may be able to get help in [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard), our chat room.

Stack Exchange is not designed to be a book, library, or link review site.  It just doesn't work well that way.  Asking for libraries and tools often attracts spam answers where the person answering it just drops a link to some library in an answer, without explaining anything.

> Try libXYZ.

Questions like "What is the best book to learn Java from" are incredibly broad, polling questions that have no right answer, only opinions.  There are hundreds (if not thousands) of books on Java.  Often times these books become outdated as fast as the technology does.

#### We do book review and suggestions poorly

One of the classic recommendation questions is that of a book.

We do book reviews very poorly. All the answers that one gets are opinions and this is fundamentally a poll of opinions. This is to say nothing of that the technology behind them changes too.  There are indeed timeless books (and [many have written on the subject](https://www.google.com/search?q=timeless+computer+books)), though their value is a [matter of debate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uBpc.jpg).

Between the polling nature of the question, the opinions people have on certain books, the constantly changing target, and the site's history of producing poor quality answers to these questions (and not moderating them), asking for a book suggestion is very likely to get closed and down voted.

#### Asking for a link to something or statistics

This is a subtler meaning of the 'favorite off-site resource' part of the wording of the close reason.  Asking a question that doesn't draw upon the community's expert knowledge as programmers but rather asking it to be a crowdsourced search engine falls into this area.

Links to things suffer from link rot.  Statistics become out of date over time.  Neither of these contribute significantly to the collective knowledge of problem solving that the Q&A format provides.

An example of this is someone asking in 2012 "What is the market share of Android vs iPhone?"  This information would be out of date in a few months as new numbers come out and someone else would ask in 2013 "The question [link] asks about the stats, but they are all for 2012.  What is the market share for android vs iPhone in 2013?"  And again, this information would be out of date and prompt another question.

Asking for information about statistics, or more generally, asking us to search for some data for you is off topic because of these problems:

- No actual problem to solve
- Not drawing from expert knowledge of the community
- Will suffer from link rot or become out of date

#### Link Rot

Furthermore, external resources may move or be deleted for a variety of reasons. Perhaps a particular site reorganizes its links without setting up redirects. Perhaps an organization goes out of business or discontinues product X or library Y.

In addition to the reasons stated above, external resources tend to be *transient*. Whatever tool, library, or other resource who requested might not exist in five years or be otherwise readily available. This has the effect of making an answer utterly useless.

If one asks for a library to perform function X, and the answer links to web site Y, and either function X or web site Y cease to exist as defined in the answer, that answer is now useless.

This is one more reason why questions like this tend to be of low value and are off-topic.

#### Is there a place where I can ask such questions?

Asking for software recommendations is on topic at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  However, if you decide to repost the question on that site, the required information for posting a question has a *much* higher threshold.  From the [ground rules](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/455/how-to-ask-and-answer-software-recommendation-questions-aka-the-ground-rules) and [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information), you will need to describe your specific need *in detail*.  If you are unsure how to frame such a question, please ask in the [SoftwareRec chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12851/software-recommendations) before posting.

#### Related reading

- (MSE) [Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75674/the-halting-problem-or-the-fallacy-of-real-questions-have-answers/75717#75717)
- (MSO) [What exactly is a recommendation question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question)
- [Are book recommendations on-topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/are-book-recommendations-on-topic)
- [Why asking for books recommendation is OffTopic and be closed instead?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3674/why-asking-for-books-recommendation-is-offtopic-and-be-closed-instead)
- (MSE) [Should / Let's close old Recommendation questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136648/should-lets-close-old-recommendation-questions)
- (MSE) [Why are “shopping list” questions bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad)
- [Why book questions tend to get downvoted and closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2204/why-book-questions-tend-to-get-downvoted-and-closed)
- [Is our current process of handling resource request questions sufficient?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4100/is-our-current-process-of-handling-resource-request-questions-sufficient)
- (SO Blog) [Gorilla vs. Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)
- (SO Blog) [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Quick link: <sub><sup>`[Why was my question closed as "Off Topic - Requests for Recommendations?"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6487/)`</sup></sub>

Comment: Nothing like directing people to a recommendation site that is in beta and doesn't have crap on it. The entire reason programmers was created in the first place was for all of the questions that weren't allowed on stackoverflow.  Limiting people from asking for a generic list of software (without without opinions) is just stupid.

Comment: @MatthewWhited recommendation questions on Programmers.SE have typically produced very low quality answers that work against the high quality content that we try to foster. While software recommendations is a beta site, it has quality guidelines and a community that is designed to try to answer recommendation questions. The way to get more activity on the beta site is to try to redirect questions that *can* be asked there in a productive way. Programmers.SE is not Not Programming Related and the site has taken a focus on software engineering and design - not the catch all it was before.

Comment: This standard is really inconsistently held up. I just got my question put "on hold" but there are lots like it that are very similar, "I need a learning resource for my special situation". Its actually very inconsiderate of peoples' time to not be consistent with this as people take the time to ask these questions and then just get them removed despite others existing that are so similar. I've seen at least one that is marked as a duplicate so they are even getting attention of moderators.

Comment: @Bren there are tens of thousands of questions out there from several years of asking.  Many of these have fallen through the cracks over time and the community wasn't always in agreement about what to do with them. However, today we are and see the problem with the resource request type questions and new questions are handled promptly. The old ones that people rarely see are rarely seen and so we don't get to close them. If you *do* happen to find such a question that is open, please flag it for closure so that it may be handled (and possibly removed).

Comment: I see no point in why all book-related questions should be closed. There are many topics that have a very sparse amount resources that are useful and it is a shame not to be able to use the developer-community's knowledge about these resources. IMHO this hurts the community in scaring away people and it makes the site less useful. Many of these types of questions have upvoted answers that prove their usefulness to the users.

Comment: @span because we have seen time and time again, when someone asks a book recommendation post they get an answer that is one sentence and a link to the book. These are poor quality answers, and questions that encourage or solicit such poor quality answers are themselves poor quality.

Comment: @MichaelT I agree that low quality answers and posts should be deleted/locked/cast away. I think the up votes on these types of questions show that the bring value and thus are not all are low quality. That low quality answers slip through should not be reason to remove questions of a certain type that can generate useful information.

Comment: @span we do occasionally (rarely) get good answers to book recommendation questions. However, the overwhelming, vast majority are just "I found book XYZ helpful". Leaving these questions open to get more answers like that doesn't help the quality of the material on the site.  On the other hand, a number of people have slowly been editing into the tag wikis book recommendation lists.  You can see this in [the agile tag](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tags/agile/info) as an example. That is the correct place for book recommendation lists - not main site questions and answers.

Comment: I don't agree with this policy. Poor signal-to-noise ratio answers don't imply the question itself is poor. Why not let users sort out the quality of answers (and questions) by voting instead of removing the questions up front citing policy? I think Reddit does a really good job with this issue, I don't see why StackExchange can't.

Comment: @amos Reddit has focused its tools and culture on discussion. It does a very good job of it. Slant has even more focused on the "recommend the best" approach. The thing is, when a question has too many answers, the quality keeps dropping, the noise goes up, and we really start getting abysmal quality. In theory, users do sort by voting, in practice they upvote everything and it becomes impossible to curate. For example, look at [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/39/40980) and consider how many of those answers are duplicates (and there are 14 deleted answers, many dups).

Comment: Alternatively, consider how hard it is to dig through a reddit post with dozens of nested conversations to find *the* answer to a coding problem (go dig around /r/javahelp on a popular post) or how easy it is to find the post in the first place. Not all types of questions work on all sites - and trying to make one site on which all questions "work", well, you find Yahoo Answers in that space.

Comment: I read Yahoo Answers when google puts them at the top of my search...

Comment: @amos I would encourage you to explore the rest of the material they provide. While google is good at picking out the quality material, it may not be representative of the material of the *rest* of the site. That we are able to attract people who provide quality answers here is in part contingent on providing those people who answer the questions with quality questions. Early on in this site's history, it was an 'anything goes' and while it was interesting for water cooler conversation, it was very much unhelpful for the hard and useful questions and answers that we regularly provide now.

Comment: (sorry, I intended this to be a part of the previous comment). Another site which does a good job of allowing users to sort out answers is Quora (although I'm not as familiar with it).

It seems odd to me how many of the questions I google take me to fantastic Stack Overflow answers which have since been closed.

I don't mind doing some digging based on poor answers and/or votes where answers are less "provable". It doesn't matter if signal-to-noise is low, at least some signal is present. My alternative in many cases is sorting through google's pagerank which is worse.

Comment: @amos You *do* realize that there is an entire SE site that is dedicated to software recommendations and has a community around curating those questions? http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ - its just that here, on Programmers.SE, we've had trouble with people providing low quality answers in the past. Though again, Quora is a different site with a different model for how it works. But it has a different group of people answering the questions - if you want *this* group of people to answer it *here*, it is important to follow the rules for the site.

Comment: @amos I will also point out that this post is an explanation of the policy. It is not the place that the policy formed or that I wrote it out of whole cloth.  The "software recommendations are off topic on Programmers.SE" close reason evolved from *all* of the 'related reading' above and a significant amount of back and forth over the years about these questions. If you really believe that it should be otherwise, I would encourage you to ask a new question on meta.

Comment: Ah, I was unaware of softwarerecs.SE, that sounds like what I need (I apologize, I didn't notice that addendum to this post above). I thought that programmers.SE *was* the more opinion-oriented flipside to stackoverflow. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: This is ridiculous. I got downvoted and warned for side-asking for example open source projects. It looks we have yet another stupid taboo in programmers SE. Keep up the good job guys!

Comment: @MisterSmith it is important to focus on the question that you have and not to ask tangential questions - especially ones that would lead to partial answers to questions that you aren't asking.  If you include "Do you know of any open source project where this has been done?" there are people who will answer that and *only* that - and those answers won't be high quality and lead to only noise in the post for other users.

Comment: @MichaelT It is not my fault if there's people who only reads the last line of a multi-paragraph question. I wasn't asking for the "best open source project where X is done" (best is also another taboo BTW)

Comment: @MisterSmith nope. But that places added work on the people who try to keep the questions and answers having a high S/N ratio. The person asking the question should try to ask the question in a way that leads to the good answers rather than posing multiple questions that allow the post to be answered without actually answering the core question.

Comment: @MichaelT Maybe we should add a "no multiple questions" new entry then? Meh, I give up.

Comment: One question per question is actually one of the guidelines, yes.

Answer (score 6):

## Other

Questions can be closed with a custom reason.  These are found in the comments for the question.  To that extent it is difficult to enumerate all the possible reasons people may try to close a question.

The essence of Software Engineering SE was summed up in chat by Thomas Owens:

> Picture Software Engineering like a small conference room with a whiteboard. No computer, no books, no papers. You write your question on the whiteboard and experts walk by. Someone sees one that they can answer, they stop in and help.

Read the explanation.

#### Related reading

- [How can I write a good custom close message?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6251/how-can-i-write-a-good-custom-close-message)
- [Why do certification questions keep getting closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6442/why-do-certification-questions-keep-getting-closed)
- [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)
- [Discuss this ${blog}](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6417/discuss-this-blog)
- [Why do interview questions make poor Software Engineering.SE questions?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6360/why-do-interview-questions-make-poor-programmers-se-questions)
- [Current events - Questions and answers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6283/current-events-questions-and-answers)
- [What types of legal questions are on-topic here?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1655/what-types-of-legal-questions-are-on-topic-here)
- (MSE) [cross-posting (posting the same question over multiple Stack Exchange sites)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Quick link: <sub><sup>`[Why was my question closed - other reasons?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6492/)`</sup></sub>

Answer (score 4):

## Off topic

#### Assistance in writing or debugging existing code

> Questions asking for **assistance in writing or debugging existing code** are off-topic here. These questions can be asked on Stack Overflow if they include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See [How To Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Asking for debugging help or “how do I write this specific code” type questions are off topic on Software Engineering SE.

These questions have a site that is completely focused on them – Stack Overflow. Trying to answer them here reduces the usefulness of Stack Overflow (now you have to search two sites for the same information), and makes it harder to find the software architecture and design questions that Software Engineering SE focuses on.

---

If you are having trouble posting a question on Stack Overflow, and have come to Software Engineering SE as a way to get around that, look ***very*** closely at the quality of the post.

- Make sure the words are all spelled correctly, and punctuation is properly used (see [Spell Check plus.com](http://spellcheckplus.com) as one of many online grammar checkers).
- Make sure that the code is formatted correctly (see [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) if you are having trouble with this).
- Make sure that the *title* of the question is a good title that describes the actual problem: “Why can't I use `==` to compare strings” is a better title than “Help, I have a question about compilers”.

Software Engineering SE is reluctant to migrate questions to Stack Overflow that would result in the question being closed there too.  The reasons on SO are covered in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the SO help center.  In particular, a “why isn't this code working” question about debugging existing code needs to thoroughly and completely describe the problem – nobody can *guess* what you're trying to do.

Neither Software Engineering SE nor Stack Overflow is a code writing service. Questions asking someone to write code from scratch (or from some requirements provided) will be closed on both sites.

If you are blocked from asking questions on Stack Overflow, please do not ask them here in an attempt to get around the block.  Both Software Engineering SE and Stack Overflow have automatic question bans in place.  Asking off topic questions here will get them closed. Even if it's a good question that might be migrated to Stack Overflow because it wouldn't get closed – the system prevents us from migrating those.

#### Related reading

- [Why are implementation and debugging questions off-topic on Software Engineering?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7864/)

Quick link: `[Why was my question closed as "Off Topic – Assistance in Writing or Debugging Existing Code?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7742)`

Answer (score 3):

## Off topic

#### Legal Advice or Aid

> Questions asking for **legal advice or aid** are off-topic here. You may be able to get help with understanding, applying, and complying with free and open licenses on [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You may be able to get help with legal terms, concepts, language, and procedures on [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Software is generally covered by copyright: even the lack of copyright (e.g. public domain) is important. When software is covered by copyright, it is often licensed to end users or other developers when it is distributed.

This is a very important topic: as software professionals, it is incumbent on us to ensure that we comply with the legal requirements of copyright law and software licenses. We may also be interested in our own rights under copyright law as well as finding a license for our own software that meets our needs.

Software Engineering SE is primarily concerned with the *software lifecycle*, not legal issues. Furthermore, many people are simply not qualified to dispense advice that borders on or falls into the legal realm: nor would any sane person do so on a web site even if qualified.

Further compounding the lack of legal expertise is the fact that the internet is a global entity, with developers in numerous legal jurisdictions. Much like with career and education advice, there are simply too many variables to give an answer to a question in a way that works for the Q&A format in the majority of cases. Even if we could dispense quality legal advice or aid, it would be far too localized to be suitable for this site.

Software Engineering SE *can* give advice on licensing questions that requires the expert knowledge of a *programmer* as opposed to a *lawyer*. However, [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is generally a much better resource for licensing questions.

If a question seeks information about copyright law but is not seeking legal advice, [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) may be an appropriate site on which to ask.

#### Related reading

- [Are software law questions off-topic here?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2099/)
- [When is a software licensing question on topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7265/)

Quick link: `[Why was my question closed as "Off Topic – Legal Advice or Aid](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8335)`