# How is this question not focussed?

Tags: discussion

"*[Which programming languages support closures?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/436081/which-programming-languages-support-closures)*" seems pretty straight forward and focussed?

That is, there is a clear question, a reference to what closures are (so there cannot be confusion), and a request for a fairly clear-cut answer.

## Some background

Selecting the right language to develop an application in is *incredibly* important. Certain things are easily achieved in programming languages with closures that are not as elegantly/easily achieved in languages without.

It's therefore a consideration in the process of planning which programming language a software tool, library or application will be written in.

#### Question

How is this question in need of "more focus"?

Comment: It seems like this falls under the "big list of things" reasoning for closure described in a [prior meta answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6490/352369)

Comment: [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7537/1204)

Comment: @Tyberius if that's why, the mod who closed it on such grounds should state so, such that it can be refuted. We can cover 99% of programming language usage in <50 languages, which is hardly "big". It's [stated](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6490) that these "big lists" have the characteristic of ***no definitive right answer that someone can go to*** - whereas the linked question ***does*** have verifiably right and wrong (or as I say, "clear-cut") answers.

Comment: You should read  the post I linked.  It contains definitive answers to your questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7537/why-do-some-examples-and-list-of-things-questions-get-closed)

Comment: @gnat and Robert "*some*". Also, see my refutation. The reason *big* lists are not allowed is because they are sometimes unable to be declared wrong or right. So my question is different in 2 ways: 1. Every single answer is verifiably wrong or right. 2. It is not "big" ([e.g.](https://madnight.github.io/githut/#/pull_requests/2021/4) the top 50 languages account for approximately 99% of all programming). A problem is the burden of proof is on the intellectually curious. It's [not the first time](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9178).

Comment: @stevec: your argument shows you stopped reading that other meta post after the first sentence. Im am sure you can do better. What's confusing here is the wording "needs more focus". This is a horrible wording, in the past the same close reason was worded as "too broad". Unfortunately, we cannot change that wording, it is a predefined reason implemented for all SE sites by the SE superiors.

Comment: @DocBrown this is like myth busters meets whack a mole. Every time I debunk some faux rationale, another one pops up to take its place. Did you read the 2 differences I stated above that set my question apart? What is it about my question *specifically* that makes **you** think the list of answers is "big"? And why is it **you** think *any single one* answer could possibly fail to be definitive? Please do what not one detractor has done and state a coherent argument.

Comment: @stevec: All I could tell you is already contained in Thomas Owens answer.

Answer (score 8):

See: [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7537/why-do-some-examples-and-list-of-things-questions-get-closed)

List questions are totally inappropriate for the Q&A format. They tend to generate lots of answers where people may name one or two languages. They become a popularity contest - what does voting mean when there are many answers with pieces of a correct answer but no correct answer?

I'm not a fan of the "needs more focus" descriptive text, but it's the best close reason that fits, particularly the first sentence: "Update the question so it focuses on one problem only." What is the problem you are facing and how can we, as software engineering practitioners, help solve it? If you can resolve that issue, perhaps it would be appropriate to consider for reopening.