# My book-recommendation question on very specific topic was deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, recommendations

This is my deleted [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/335466/is-there-any-kind-of-book-course-about-hacking-as-opposed-to-proper-software-e).

From this meta question I conclude that it's acceptable to ask for course/book recommendations on specialized topics: [Are book recommendations on-topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/are-book-recommendations-on-topic)

So, can I do anything for my question to be reopened? Is there other SE site where this question would be more appropriate?

Comment: The opening sentence in the top answer to the Meta question you reference is: _Book requests fall into the "outside resources" close reason and should be closed._ We did allow some book questions a few years back (notice that the answer is from 2011), but even then I think your question would be closed as it's rather broad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have a question, but it may not fit best on Software Engineering. Where else can I ask it?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8066/i-have-a-question-but-it-may-not-fit-best-on-software-engineering-where-else-c)

Comment: see also: [Why was my question closed or down voted?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487)

Comment: What part of the answer to that meta questions makes you come to that conclusion? Please tell us, then we can edit the top answer to make it more clearer, to avoid such misunderstandings.

Comment: @DocBrown "However, like programming language questions, if you have specialised requirements (you want to go into LINQ, or networking, or.. in great depth) then perhaps those should be allowed."

Comment: @user713303: ok, I got it, added a clearer statement that the lower part of the answer is not applicable any more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why was my question so quickly deleted by a moderator?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8350/why-was-my-question-so-quickly-deleted-by-a-moderator)

Answer (score 5):

The [Help Center's page about what can be asked here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has a list of types questions that are not allowed, even if they fall into one of the things that are considered on-topic here:

> Some questions, even if they appear to fit into one of the above
>   categories, may still be off-topic or a poor fit for this format:
>
> - explaining, writing or debugging code
> - providing support for tools or products
> - finding or recommending products or services, including tools, libraries or packages, programming languages, books, scholarly papers,
>     tutorials, articles, or blogs
> - career or education advice
> - legal advice or aid

That links to [a Meta post that explains in great detail why recommendation or list questions don't fit into the Q&A format well](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487). The [Meta question that you link to](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/are-book-recommendations-on-topic) is listed as related reading in that post. Both answers in the question you found indicate that book recommendation questions are not a good fit.

The question was deleted [on the advice of Shog9, one of the Stack Exchange CMs, in The Whiteboard, our site's chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21?m=31225279#31225279):

> Same way we do it on MSE every day: delete everything that's blatantly off-topic as soon as it appears.

Although this was specifically in response to code dumps, we have had specific problems with five particular types of questions: explaining/debugging code, support for products/tools, recommendations, career or education advice, and legal advice or aid. These are the five off-topic questions specifically called out in the Help Center as not belonging here. If I cannot migrate questions in these types to a more appropriate site, I close using the appropriate off-topic reason and immediately delete. By deleting them, they don't show up in searches and people generally can't browse to them and think that they belong here. Many people don't understand that questions that are on-hold or closed mean that they shouldn't be asked here, so getting rid of them entirely helps present a better picture of what's acceptable to ask in the future.